# Filtering Child Categories in Solspace Super Search

Tags: solspace, search, filter, supersearch, gwcode-categories

I've a working Super Search form, need to filter a category search result page
{site_url}/event/results/search&category=sport/

where sport is a parent category.
working form is...

{!----------- SUPER SEARCH FORM -------------------------------------------}

```
<form method="post" action="{path='event/results'}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="search-box" data-abide>
{exp:super_search:search channel="main_event" status="open|featured"}
{if super_search_category}<input type="hidden" name="category" value="{super_search_category}" />{/if}

<div class="row">
<div class="large-6 columns">
<label for="sort">Location:</label>
<small class="error">Please Choose Event</small>
<select name="category[]" id="event" data-placeholder="All Events" style="width:100%" required>
<option></option>
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" show_empty="no" parent_only="yes" style="linear"}
<option value="{category_url_title}">{category_name}</option>
{/exp:channel:categories}
</select>
</div>
{/exp:super_search:search}
</form>
```

{!----------- /SUPER SEARCH FORM -------------------------------------------}

The parent category **sport** have some child categories, i need to dynamically filter the results page via a select drop-down the child categories of the searched parent category.

With [GWcode](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) Categories plugin, was able to come up with this

```
<select name="category" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}" id="multi" data-placeholder="Select" style="width:100%" />
<option></option>
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="main_event" group_id="1" excl_group_id="3|4" show_empty="no" cat_id="{segment_3_category_id}" depth="2" style="linear"}
<option value="{site_url}event/results/search&category={super_search_category}&&{cat_url_title}" {if super_search_category_{cat_url_title}}selected="selected"{/if}>{cat_name}</option>
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
</select>
```

I think i'm very close but the [GWcode](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) tags code isn't perfect and stable because after a first successful filtering..
{site_url}event/results/search&category=sport&&soccer

trying to filter again, i got this
{site_url}event/results/search&category=sport&&soccer&&tennis

instead of

{site_url}event/results/search&category=sport&&tennis

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any AJAX to submit the form or display the child categories (after selecting a parent category)?

Comment: No, just a manual search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your second block of code is that the option values for the `category` select field is a URL, when it should be category data, such as a category_id, category_url_title or category_name.

Let's say your first search with the first dropdown sends you to http://mysite.com/event/results/search&category=sports

On this result page, you can create another search form, and pass the previous search's values. In this case, you could pass "sports" in a hidden field, for example:

```
{if super_search_category != ""}
<input type="hidden" name="category[]" value="{super_search_category}&&" />
{/if}
```

**Please note the brackets in `category[]`**. This is needed to be able to submit an *array* of category data. If you forget this, you are sending a single *string* of data, i.e. only the last filled field with name="category". The `&&` is to enable an AND search with other categories. (The alternative is to use `inclusive_categories="yes"` in {exp:super_search:results})

In addition to the above in your search form on your result page, just create a dropdown with your child categories. Use whatever you need for this, GWcode or other. The important is to

- use `name="category[]"` here again
- pass category data in the option's value="" attribute (not a URL). Add `&&` at the end to specify that categories are to be searched inclusively.

In other words, try getting something like this:

```
<select name="category[]">
   <option value="soccer&&">Soccer</option>
   <option value="tennis&&">Tennis</option>
   ...
</select>
```

If you select "Tennis", for example, in this second search submission, you should be sent to  http://mysite.com/event/results/search&category=sports&&tennis

No messy javascript to mess with either! :)

Comment: Hi,
made the suggested modifications on the results page. The second search submission link is being directed to http://mysite.com/event/results/search&category=sports/tennis, the && is missing.

Comment: Any way you can show your code after the first submission? Make sure the hidden field is **before** the select field.

Comment: Sure, but i can't because the code is too long.. due to StackExchange comment field characters limitation.

Comment: I updated my answer above. There was a missing `&&` for the select field `category[]` field